# Spring Boot SAML Integration with Wso2 Identity Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have to integrate my sprint boot Application with latest version 3.1.2, I have to use SAML Authentication protocol and Integrate the same with wso2 Identity server,can i get any references or documentations for Integrating Wso2 Identity Server with my Sprint Boot Application through **SAML Authentication protocol**

Comment: please check this blogs: https://piraveenaparalogarajah.medium.com/add-saml-authentication-to-spring-boot-app-with-wso2-is-17ed3d12c60d, https://www.chakray.com/wso2-identity-server-integration-spring-boot-security-saml/

Answer (score 0):

Since SAML is a standard protocol, configuring WSO2 Identity Server correctly should make your app work without any issue. You can find the official documentation about SAML in here.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/login/sso-for-saml/#try-it-out

However, if you are looking for a tutorial on how to configure Spring Boot with WSO2 Identity Server, I would suggest to follow this.

https://piraveenaparalogarajah.medium.com/add-saml-authentication-to-spring-boot-app-with-wso2-is-17ed3d12c60d